# Issue translating Access Logic to Pandas in python 3.8

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, logic, legacy-code

I'm currently working to transfer some projects from access databases to Python 3.8 using pandas.
I've been running into an issue with the logic for one of the queries. The MSACCESS query is as follows:

```
UPDATE tblStagingMaternity AS tblStaging SET tblStaging.FlagExclude = 4
WHERE tblStaging.FlagExclude=0 AND NOT (tblStaging.CLCL_NTWK_IND='I' OR tblStaging.CLCL_NTWK_IND='P' OR tblStaging.PR_PRPR_STS='PA');
```

I thought the Python equivalent would be

```
Stage_Maternity_DF.loc[((Stage_Maternity_DF['FlagExclude'] == 0) &
                      (~((Stage_Maternity_DF['CLCL_NTWK_IND'].isin(['I','P'])) |
                        (Stage_Maternity_DF['PR_PRPR_STS'].isin(['PA']))))),
                      'FlagExclude'] = 4
```

Unfortunately I've found that in Access there are entries where `CLCL_NTWK_IND` or `PR_PRPR_STS` are blank they stay `FlagExclude = 0`. In the pandas/Python code it sets the `FlagExclude = 4`.

I know that `&` is evaluated before other operators so I've tried using various different sets of parentheses with the code as well as including `''` in the `.isin` statements but it continue to evaluate the blank entries to `4`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest explicitly treating blanks before filtering.

For example, consider the following as a pre-processing step before you filter (may need to update for your data types/values)

```
df.fillna(value = 0, inplace = True)
```

or

```
df.replace('Missing', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Question.. should the FlagExclude condition be inside the parenthesis?

```
,'FlagExclude' = 4]
```

Comment: Tried doing something similar (replaced the rows in the two columns that had an empty space with 0s.  It was still incorrect.